# JavaScript onblur event handling

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am currently learning JavaScript and am having trouble with manipulating events. I want to add an event that will register the input in some `text` fields in HTML, manipulate them, and display a result in an `alert` box.

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <form name="order" onSubmit="totalPrice()">
        <p><label><input type="text" name="apples" onblur="apples()"/> Apples</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="text" name="oranges" onblur="oranges()"/> Oranges</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="text" name="bananas" onblur="bananas()"/> Bananas</label></p>
        <p><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Query"/></p>
    </form>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
    var total = 0;

    function apples ()
    {
        var a = document.order.apples.value;

        total += a * 0.75;
    }

    function oranges ()
    {
        var o = document.order.oranges.value;

        total += o * 0.60;
    }

    function bananas ()
    {
        var b = document.order.bananas.value;

        total += b * 0.50;
    }

    function totalPrice ()
    {
        window.alert("Thank you for your order!\nYour total cost is: " + total);
    }
```

Now, if I call the `apples()`, `oranges()`, and `bananas()` in the `totalPrice()` function it works no problem, but the call from the `input` tags does not seem to work.

Comment: You need to name your functions differently then the inputs names. It was answerd by @VladuIonut but he deleted the answer.

Comment: His answer is still here for me.

Comment: I think that he undeleted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to name the inputs differently from the functions

```js
// Code goes here

  var total = 0;

    function apples_func ()
    {
        var a = document.order.apples.value;

        total += a * 0.75;
    }

    function oranges_func ()
    {
        var o = document.order.oranges.value;

        total += o * 0.60;
    }

    function bananas_func()
    {
        var b = document.order.bananas.value;

        total += b * 0.50;
    }

    function totalPrice ()
    {
     // apples();
      //oranges();
      //bananas();
        window.alert("Thank you for your order!\nYour total cost is: " + total);
    }
```

```html
  <form name="order" onSubmit="totalPrice()">
        <p><label><input type="text" name="apples" onblur="apples_func()"/> Apples</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="text" name="oranges" onblur="oranges_func()"/> Oranges</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="text" name="bananas" onblur="bananas_func()"/> Bananas</label></p>
        <p><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Query"/></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: The issue with your answer is that if you focus put a value (like 2) blur then focus again the input and inform a new one (like 3) it will add them each time.
For apples it will do: 
2*0.75 + 3*0.75 on the total

Comment: Thank you both! Yes @Sacreyoule the total doesn't work the way it should, but that's just bad programming on my part, I think I can fix it.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation or a reference for this behavior? The reason for the name conflict is not obvious since: window.document.myForm.myInput  != window.myFunc when names are same. Thanks.

Comment: you can find a fix for @Sacreyoule issue http://plnkr.co/edit/gDeeDwvHqKJffLjkCelw?p=info

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a generic function and use the name attribute of each fruit:

```
<form name="order" onSubmit="totalPrice()">
    <p><label><input type="text" name="apples" onblur="inputBlur(this)"/> Apples</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="text" name="oranges" onblur="inputBlur(this)"/> Oranges</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="text" name="bananas" onblur="inputBlur(this)"/> Bananas</label></p>
    <p><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Query"/></p>
</form>
```

And JS looks like:

```
var fruitNumbers = {apple: 0, orange: 0, banana: 0};
var total = 0;
var prices = {apple: 0.75, orange: 0.6, banana: 0.5}

function inputBlur(fruitInput){
    var fruit = fruitInput.getAttribute('name');
    fruitNumbers[fruit] = this.value;
    calculateTotal();
}

function calculateTotal(){
    total = 0;
    for(fruit in fruitNumbers){
        total += fruitNumbers[fruit] * prices[fruit];
    }
}

function totalPrice ()
{
    window.alert("Thank you for your order!\nYour total cost is: " + total);
}
```